# How do I debug in LiteIDE with breakpoints, step into, step over, etc?

Tags: debugging, go, ide

I would like to know it there is a way to run debug for Go chaincode in LiteIDE (or any other) and be able to use some standard features like breakpoints in the code,  Step Into & Step Over commands, watch variables as any step, etc. 
In some other environments it is possible to attach IDE to some process for debugging with all that features.

---

Background:

I'm new to Go and IBM Hyperledger and now I'm trying to clarify the question in the Title.

Prerequisites:

1. I've completed chaincode setup by the Option 1 (using Vagrant) in the tutorial: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/
2. I'm able to write, build, deploy and invoke Go chaincode to the peer which is run with --peer-chaincodedev flag.
3. My OS is Windows 8 and Ubunty 14.04.4 LTS runs in Vagrant
4. I use LiteIDE for Go chaincode development

Comment: This is more a question that asks for tooling. This is not regarded as a good question. At least show what you have tried. A simple search reveals  https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/06/debugging-golang-using-liteide-on-ubuntu-14-04/. That article shows how to use LiteIDE with golang

Comment: @Sascha, thank you for your answer. It's clear how to debug regular Go application but it's not clear how to use it in hyperledger chaincode specific case. And, more specifically, when set up is done in the way of Option 1 which is described in the doc.  In the setup we use Windows like host OS (optionally) and Ubuntu (by Vagrant virtualization) for running chaincode itself.  Is it possible to use LiteIDE debug in that case? Or should I run LiteIDE and Go chaincode in the same OS? There should be developers who tried chaincode debugging and faced similar issues.